# How to generate list of numbers from hyphenated and comma separeted string in Perl

Tags: perl

In Perl, how to generate list of numbers from hyphen/comma string like:
*1-8,10,12-15,23* ?
Expected output is: *[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15,23]*

Ok, I have some solution that seems to work, can I optimize it? :

```
@cl_list = "0,2-7,13-16"
@cl_list = split(/,/,join(',',@cl_list));

foreach $cl (@cl_list){
    if (index($cl, '-') != -1){ 
        @range=split(/-|,/,$cl,2);
        $ld=$range[0];
        $ud=$range[1];

        while ($ld <= $ud) {
            push @list, $ld;
            print "$ld\n";
           $ld++;         
        }
    }
    else {
        push @list, $ld;
    }
}
print "list=@list\n";
```

Comment: Have a look at [Set::IntSpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::IntSpan) from CPAN.

Comment: Try some of your own code first, then post here what does not work.

Comment: I'm newbie to perl, that's why I'm asking - because have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $thing = '1-8,10,12-15,23'; 
my @values; 

#split the string on commas.    
for ( split /,/, $thing ) { 
    #split each element in `-`. ($end is undefined if no `-` present)
    my ( $start, $end ) = split ( '-' );
    #iterate from start to end (or start to start if end is undef)
    push ( @values, $_ ) for ( $start .. $end // $start );
}

print join ",", @values;
```

Prints:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,13,14,15,23
```

Comment: here is problem: my ( $start, $end ) = split ( '-',$_  ); - missing $_

Comment: besides this command: "push ( @values, $_ ) for ( $start..$end//$start );" gives error: Search pattern not terminated at a.pl line 14.

Comment: Definitely does work. You may have an older perl version. Try `||` instead of `//` - it works _almost_ the same, with this input data. Likewise `split` - default to splitting `$_` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is fixed Sobrique solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $thing = '1-8,10,12-15,23'; 
my @values; 

#split the string on commas.    
for ( split /,/, $thing ) { 
    #split each element in `-`. ($end is undefined if no `-` present)
    my ( $start, $end ) = split ( '-',$_  );
    if (!defined $end) { $end=$start;}
    #iterate from start to end (or start to start if end is undef)
    push ( @values, $_ ) for ( $start..$end );
}

print join ",", @values;
```